# How to get only X numbers from a string as an Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following a string like:

```
"Your number 2328681 is not in range [2428681 - 3328681]"
```

I need to get only the second two numbers `2428681` and `3328681` in a list or array anything that lets me read them separately.

After searching I found this function `match()` and tried doing the following:

```
var thestring = "Your number 2328681 is not in range [2428681 -3328681]"
var numb = thestring.match(/\d/g);
numb = numb.join("")
alert(numb)
```

or using `replace()`

```
var thestring = "Your number 2328681 is not in range [2428681 -3328681]"
var num = thestring.replace(/\D/g, '');
alert (num)
```

In both cases I get `"232868124286813328681"` I don't know how to transform it into a list with the two last numbers like  `[2428681, 3328681]`

Comment: use a capturing group.

Comment: If your numbers are **always** between brackets and there is no other bracket anywhere, you don't even need the regex.

Comment: yes sir my numbers will always be between brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take all the numbers, and `slice` the result to remove the first found:

```js
s = "Your number 2328681 is not in range [2428681 -3328681]";
g = s.match(/(-?\d+)/g);
console.log(g);
console.log(g.slice(1));
```

Another option, since you said the numbers are always inside the brackets, you can use that information:

```js
s = "Your number 2328681 is not in range [2428681 -3328681]";
g = s.match(/\[(-?\d+).*?(-?\d+)\]/);
console.log(g);
console.log(g.slice(1));
```

Comment: There's a problem with this, it won't take the `-` into consideration.

Comment: Added this to the answer as well :)

Comment: this one works perfectly!! waiting to accept your answer thank you all!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var str = "Your number 2328681 is not in range [2428681 -3328681]";
var spl1 = str.split("[")[1].split(" ").map(it => parseInt(it));
```

Final result:

[image]

Comment: This is not gonna work since you're spliting by `-` which indicates a negative number, if both are positive it will fail.

Comment: After edit, I think this is the simplest and the best solution

Answer (score 1):

Here's how i would do it, first, i'd split the string on open brackets.

```
functions(str){
  str.split("[")
}
```

then take the last element, which will be a string of your two numbers `"2428681 -3328681]"`

```
functions(str){
      str.split("[")[1]
    }
```

then, trim off that trailing bracket

```
functions(str){
  var newstr = str.split("[")[1]
  newstr = newstr.slice(0, -1)
}
```

then, split again, on spaces, that should give you the final array. So we wind up with

```
functions(str){
  var newstr = str.split("[")[1]
  newstr = newstr.slice(0, -1)
  return newstr.split(" ")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```js
var thestring = "Your number 2328681 is not in range [2428681 -3328681]".match(/\[(.*?)\]/);
console.log(thestring[1].split(" "))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```js
let str = "Your number 2328681 is not in range [2428681 -3328681]"

let result = str.match(/\[(-?\d+) (-?\d+)\]/);

if(result)
    result.shift();
console.log(result);
```